# What is the right code for JsonResult using Asp.net MVC Core 3.1?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I'm using Asp.Net MVC Core3.1 "code first" : i have issue with "JsonResult" :  JsonResult: doesn't recognize so what the solution ?

The error say :  Error  CS1729  'JsonResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  Attendance

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            using (MyDbContext dc = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var events = dc.rotation.ToList();
                return new JsonResult(){ Data = events , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

            }
        }
```

Comment: ``return Json(new { Data = events }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`` can you try this instead of return row. Because ``JsonResult`` is not method.

Comment: I did and still a bit error for : JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet :
Error CS0103 The name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist in the current

Comment: Oh okay, this must be solve your problem ``return Json(events)`` .

Comment: Yes it solved thanks but why i can not use : { Data = events , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }  ?

Comment: ``JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`` depricated in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for you you save my day .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is replace :

```
return new JsonResult(){ Data = events , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

to

```
return Json(events)
```